# Angular11 unit testing for formBuilder for valueChanges

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Unable to cover search() function in unit testing.

I am not sure how to mock fomBuilder and FormControl.
Also the service needs to return data so how to mock it.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.search()
  }
 searchForm = this.fb.group({
    searchText: new FormControl()
  });
  subscription$: any;
  search() {
    this.subscription$ = this.searchForm.controls['searchText'].valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        tap(() => {
          this.errorMsg = '';
          this.filteredOptions = [];
          this.isLoading = true;
        }),
        switchMap((value: string) => {
          this.toHighlight = value;
          this.searchKeyword = value;
          if (value != '' && value !== undefined) {value = value.toUpperCase();  this._assetService.setSearchKey(this.toHighlight);}
          this.isLoading = true;
          return this._assetService.fetchVlmSearch(value).pipe((finalize(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
          })))
        })
      ).subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          this.filteredOptions = data.rows;
        }
        else {
          this.errorMsg = 'No Data Found';
          this.filteredOptions = [];
          this.searchKeyword = '';
        }

      })
  }
```

Comment: I can see no save() here

Comment: I meant search() @Antoniossss

Comment: There is no reason to mock form related components because they have easy to use API and does not require access trough GUI.  Just use them. assetsService can be mocked easily via providers. Wrap everything into fakeAsync to be able to synchronously skip 200 ticks to make debounce to kick in in your unit test

Comment: Also its easier and more readable (yep, my personal opinion) to use `takeUnitl($obs)` to terminate the pipeline instead of saving `Subscription` object and cancelling it later on by hand (assuming that is why you are saving it)